# Lookup Filter in Business Process flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I try to change the lookup filter for the field "Existing Contact?" (in the Lead process flow) but I cannot access the property of this field.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately BPF fields property window is not accessible and lookup field property cannot be customized the same way we do any other lookup in form sections.

But there is a way, we can use Javascript to apply the lookup filter using `addPreSearch` method. This is totally supported. [Read more](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/seanroque/2019/07/03/how-to-filter-lookups-in-a-dynamics-365-business-process-flow)

```
function filterBpfLookup = function(formContext){
    if (formContext.getControl("header_process_mag_contactlookupid") != null){
        formContext.getControl("header_process_mag_contactlookupid").addPreSearch(filterDefinition);
    }
}

function filterDefinition = function(formContext) {
     var accountId = null;
     var accountLookup;
     var filterBpf;

     if (formContext.getControl("header_process_mag_contactlookupid") != null &&
     formContext.getControl("header_process_mag_contactlookupid").getAttribute().getValue() !=  null){
         accountLookup = formContext.getControl("header_process_mag_accountlookupid").getAttribute().getValue();
         accountId = accountLookup[0].id;

         if (accountId != null || accountId != undefined){
             filterBpf = "<filter type='and'>" + 
             "<condition attribute='mag_accountlookupid' operator='eq' value='" + accountId + "' />" +
             "</filter>";

             formContext.getControl("header_process_mag_contactlookupid").addCustomFilter(filterBpf);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Arun thank you for the fast feedback, i want to know whats is the trigger for the Javascript ?

Comment: @hedibouneni it’s form onload or Account lookup onchange